# Signature4 signing for elastic search in aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-iam, aws-elasticsearch

I'm using the aws managed elasticsearch/ I'm using the high-level java client for elastic search. Is there a way to use aws signature4 signing for the requests made with the high level client?

Comment: This blog post from the AWS Security Blog may help: [How to Control Access to Your Amazon Elasticsearch Service Domain](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-control-access-to-your-amazon-elasticsearch-service-domain/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do perform the signing calculations and add the appropriate headers to your request. See [Examples: Signature Calculations in AWS Signature Version 4](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-examples-using-sdks.html)  for Java and C# examples. I took took this code and put my own interface on top:

```
import net.craigcaulfield.awsutils.signing.auth.AWS4SignerBase;
import net.craigcaulfield.awsutils.signing.auth.AWS4SignerForAuthorizationHeader;
import net.craigcaulfield.awsutils.signing.util.BinaryUtils;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * A utility for calculating an AWS Signature Version 4 signature headers for requests. See
 * http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-examples-using-sdks.html for the full description.
 *
 * @author Craig Caulfield
 */
public class SigningUtility {

    /**
     * Build the authorization headers to be added to the service request. 
     * 
     * @param regionName AWS region
     * @param url service URL
     * @param awsAccessKey AWS access key
     * @param awsSecretKey AWS secret key
     * @param messageBody the message body for POSTs
     * @param httpMethod the HTTP verb used for this message (GET, POST, etc)
     * @param serviceName the AWS service (s3, execite-api, ...)
     * @return authorisation headers to add to the request.
     */
    public Map<String, String> getAuthorisationHeader(String regionName, String url, String awsAccessKey, String awsSecretKey, 
                                                      String messageBody, String httpMethod, String serviceName) {

        URL endpointUrl;
        try {
            endpointUrl = new URL(url);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unable to parse service endpoint: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        String contentHashString;
        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
        if ("POST".equals(httpMethod)) {

            // precompute hash of the body content
            byte[] contentHash = AWS4SignerBase.hash(messageBody);
            contentHashString = BinaryUtils.toHex(contentHash);

            headers.put("x-amz-content-sha256", contentHashString);
            headers.put("content-length", "" + messageBody.length());

        } else if ("GET".equals(httpMethod)) {

            contentHashString = AWS4SignerBase.EMPTY_BODY_SHA256;
            // for a simple GET, we have no body so supply the precomputed 'empty' hash
            headers.put("x-amz-content-sha256", AWS4SignerBase.EMPTY_BODY_SHA256);

        } else {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("This utility only supports GET and POST HTTP verbs for now");
        }

        AWS4SignerForAuthorizationHeader signer = new AWS4SignerForAuthorizationHeader(
                endpointUrl, httpMethod, serviceName, regionName);

        String authorisation = signer.computeSignature(headers,
                null, // assume no query parameters
                contentHashString,
                awsAccessKey,
                awsSecretKey);

        headers.put("Authorization", authorisation);

        return headers;
    }
}
```

The `AWS4SignerBase`, `AWS4SignerForAuthorizationHeader`, `BinaryUtils` classes come directly from the AWS example. The only hard bit is finding the `serviceName` for your particular service, which for Elastic Search is probably `es`.

As an alternative, if you can make use of (and afford soapUI Pro), it has [built-in features to do all this](https://support.smartbear.com/readyapi/docs/projects/requests/auth/types/aws.html) for you.