# Generating AWS signature in Groovy for soapUI

Tags: amazon-web-services, groovy, soapui

I am new to groovy scripting and I have to test AWS Rest API for which Authorization (consist of access_key and signature) is required. Request if anyone have working code available. It is PUT call on AWS S3.

I have tried searching and unable to find the same.

Comment: Nobody has told you but you should write what you have attempted so far `i.e., the code you have written` so we can know what's going on and try to help you. this is the reason for the down-votes.

Answer (score 1):

If you can afford it, the latest versions of soapUI Pro have AWS signing built it.

Otherwise, you'll have to write your own following the steps at [Examples: Signature Calculations in AWS Signature Version 4](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-examples-using-sdks.html). There's an example at [Signature4 signing for elastic search in aws](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51544966/signature4-signing-for-elastic-search-in-aws/52418849#52418849) in Java, but it's easy enough to call from Groovy.